# Flume roll settings not working

Tags: hdfs, apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

Edit*: Here is the full config file:

```
tier1.sources = source1
tier1.channels = channel1
tier1.sinks = sink1
tier1.sources.source1.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
tier1.sources.source1.command = /usr/bin/vmstat 1
tier1.sources.source1.channels = channel1
tier1.sources.source1.kafka.consumer.timeout.ms = 20000000
tier1.channels.channel1.type = org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
tier1.channels.channel1.capacity = 10000
tier1.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 1000
tier1.channels.channel1.brokerList= ip.address:9092
tier1.channels.channel1.topic= test1
tier1.channels.channel1.zookeeperConnect=ip.address:2181
tier1.channels.channel1.parseAsFlumeEvent=false

tier1.sinks.sink1.type = hdfs
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = /user/flume/
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollInterval = 5000
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollSize = 5000
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollCount = 1000
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.idleTimeout= 10
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.maxOpenFiles=1
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
tier1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
```

I didn't have idleTimeout and maxOpenFiles till recently. So it wasn't working even with the default configurations for those 2 options.

Question on using Flume to aggregate Kafka data. Currently, Flume is creating a new file every second for reading in streaming data. These are my settings:

```
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollInterval = 500 (should be 500 seconds)
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollSize = 5000 (should be bytes)
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollCount = 1000 (number of events)
```

The one setting I'm not completely sure on is rollCount, so some additional info:

i'm getting 80 bytes/second, some of my files are 80 bytes with 2 messages, some are 160 bytes, but with 4 messages. So it's not doing it based off time or size, so it may have to be with count, but I don't see why such small messages would register as 1000 events?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Could the rollInterval be milliseconds? I think I may have had this issue before.

Comment: I thought of that as well. I changed it to 5000, so it should be 5 seconds, but am still getting the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Post the rest of your config, it may be that your source batch size etc is incorrect and having a knock on effect.